# Java list comparison resulting in error I can't pin down

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm working on this script to compare elements sequentially in a list/array in Java. Essentially the code takes in a CSV, converts it to a list and iterates over the list's size. When I attempt a comparison between the values I run into an error I can't figure out in this case:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Float (java.lang.String and java.lang.Float are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
>   at list.main(list.java:22)

The code is:

```
public class list{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter your filename");
        Scanner inputValue = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileLocation = inputValue.nextLine();
        try {
            String checkvalue = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileLocation)));
            ArrayList<Float> listValues = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(checkvalue.split("[\\r\\n]+")));
            System.out.println(listValues);
            for (int i = 0; i < listValues.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(listValues.get(i));
                float valueA = listValues.get(i);
                float valueB = listValues.get(i+1);
                if (valueA <= valueB){
                    System.out.println("True");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: String split returns a string. so `listValues` is actually an ArrayList<String> but you've declared it an `ArrayList<Float>`.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense. I'm coming from Python if that clarifies the mistake, type conversions are very straightforward compares to here. In this case, I guess I generate the list, then convert the list elements into floats afterward? Or is there a doc where I can read up on how to convert directly to a float by this method?

Comment: `new ArrayList` instantiates a raw type. You should have a warning on that line. You want `new ArrayList<Float>` or just `new ArrayList<>`.

Comment: @DanielPryden:  Technically true but there's an issue with conversion between the type of lists which would be better explained in an answer.

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, I just saw that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this line

```
ArrayList<Float> listValues = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(checkvalue.split("[\\r\\n]+")));
```

with this:

```
ArrayList<Float> listValues = new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.stream(
        checkvalue.split("[\\r\\n]+"))
            .map(Float::parseFloat).collect(Collectors.toList()
    )
);
```

Your have two main mistakes

- `new ArrayList` creates a raw type. [And you should not use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). This is why I have added `<>`.
- `Arrays.asList(checkvalue.split("[\\r\\n]+"))` creates a `List<String>`, which can't be converted to a `ArrayList<Float>`. This is why I mapped everything in the `String[]` with `Float::parseFloat`.

Or more simply, as suggested by littleLouito,

```
ArrayList<Float> listValues = Arrays.stream(
        checkvalue.split("[\\r\\n]+"))
            .map(Float::parseFloat).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: The creation of the `ArrayList` is pointless when you create a list with `toList`, since the list is never modified.'

Comment: @Lii Without creating a `new ArrayList` it won't compile.

Comment: you can use Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new) to collect directly into an ArrayList

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala: When you are saying that something doesn't compile it is helpful to say *what* is and what error message it gives. It this case the problem probably is that the type of the `listValues` variable must be changed to `List<Double>`. But that's okay in the posters code, because they doesn't need the list to be an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<Float> listValues = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(checkvalue.split("[\\r\\n]+")));
```

`checkvalue.split(...)` returns a string array. So the right hand side of this expression builds up an `ArrayList<String[]>`. You've declared `listValues` as `ArrayList<Float>`, though, so it's trying to tell you that you have a type mismatch.

To solve, you'll need to parse the Strings into floats. Java's Float class has a nice [`parseFloat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat-java.lang.String-) method you can use.

Comment: You'll need to stream it and convert using `Float.parseFloat`.